# wso2esb email transportReceiver

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using the WSO2 ESB version 4.7.0. I prepared Proxy service that uses email transportReceiver(Based on the example 256). In axis2.xml I unlock MailTransportListener in this lines:

```
<transportReceiver name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener">
</transportReceiver>
```

This is my proxy service. This service is not using the POP3 protocol but IMAP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="MailProxyPublish"
       transports="mailto"
       statistics="enable"
       trace="enable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <clone>
            <target sequence="somethingSequence10"/>
            <target sequence="somethingSequence20"/>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">20</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.starttls.enable">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.ssl.enable">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Folder">leader</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.MoveAfterProcess">PSX</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.host">mail.yyyyy.biz</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Address">grzegorz.wwww@yyyyy.biz</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.user">grzegorz.wwww.yyyyy</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Protocol">imap</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.password">hs!01</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

When the service starts up in the logs WSO2 ESB I get the error:

```
ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener} -
   Error connecting to mail server for address :grzegorz.wwww@yyyyy.biz :: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? {org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener}
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:479)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener.checkMail(MailTransportListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener.poll(MailTransportListener.java:80)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener.poll(MailTransportListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:97)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.read0(ResponseInputStream.java:81)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:67)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:83)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:48)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.readResponse(IMAPResponse.java:122)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:230)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:91)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:87)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:446)
    ... 11 more
```

What is wrong in the parameters MailTransportListener my proxy?

I wrote a java program with the same emails parameters with JavaMail library (ver 1.4, 1.4.7). It works good. Here's the code:

```
package org.homelab;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore;

public class EmailReceiveTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mailHost = "mail.yyyyy.biz";
        String mailStoreType = "imap";
        String mailUser = "grzegorz.wwww.yyyyy;
        String mailPassword = "hs!01";
        receiveEmail(mailHost, mailStoreType, mailUser, mailPassword);
    }

    public static void receiveEmail(String host, String storeType, String user,
            String password) {
        //MailTransportListener
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.imap.host", host);
            //properties.put("mail.imap.port", 143);
            //ERROR properties.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            //ERROR properties.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
            //ERROR properties.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", 143);


            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            IMAPStore emailStore = (IMAPStore) emailSession.getStore(storeType);
            emailStore.connect(user, password);
            Folder emailFolder = emailStore.getFolder("leader");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                System.out.println("==============================");
                System.out.println("Email #" + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
                System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println("Body: ");
                System.out.println( message.getContent().toString());
            }
            emailFolder.close(false);
            emailStore.close();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I reproduced the above-described error. The same error occurs when I unlocked in my code lines marked with //ERROR.

Thanks in advance, Grzegorz

Answer (score 1):

If you have send the email without plain/text you will get this error. Please refer the documents again.